# Knockout and partial view from JSON GET call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am pretty new to `KnockoutJS`. I want with JSON GET retrieve partial view and all bindings with validation.

My model:

```
public class MyFormModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999")]
        [Display(Name = Translations.WorkReport.PRICE_PER_UNIT)]
        //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#,##}")] 
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(typeof(Decimal), "1", "9999")]
        [Display(Name = Translations.WorkReport.QUANTITY)]
        //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#,##}")]  
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
...
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual PartialViewResult GetDataByGroupId(int groupId)
        {
...
var view = PartialView("WorkReportResult", createWorkReportsListFormModel);
return view
}
```

My partial view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Price)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Price,
                new
                {
                    @Value = Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Price != 0 ? Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Price.ToString() : "",
                    id = @Html.RenderNumbers("Price", i),
                    @class = "input-small focused"
                })
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Quantity)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Quantity,
                new
                {
                    @Value = Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Quantity != 0 ? Model.WorksReportsFormModel.WorkReportViewModelList[i].WorkReportFormModel.Quantity.ToString() : "",
                    id = @Html.RenderNumbers("Quantity", i),
                    @class = "input-small focused"
                })
        </td>
```

My normal view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable dataTable grid-table" id="students">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title">Price</div></th>
            <th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title">Wuantity</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="content">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my JQUERY call from this view to retrieve partial view:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                timeout: 30000,
                url: '' + baseurl + '/CustomModel/ManageWorkReport/GetDataByGroupId',
                data: { groupId: value},
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                        ...
```

but is not ok, no bindings are here. How to include `KnockoutJS`?

I found this but does not work!
https://stevemgentile.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/knockoutjs-asp-net-mvc-partial-view-loading/

Comment: I'm confused: there's *zero* knockout related bits of code in your question's code? No `data-bind`ings, no client side view models, no `applyBindings`, nothing, as far as I can tell. What do you expect from us exactly?

Comment: @Jeroen I think he want's to convert this code to using Knockout.

Comment: @JoseLuis Could be, but in that case it's a *very* broad question, or probably even more a (architectural) design question, not quite on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this:

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(self.Model);
var unmappedJSON = ko.toJSON(unmapped);

$.ajax({
            url: ...,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: unmappedJSON,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //var mapping = self.Model.IgnoreMapping();
                var mapping = []
                var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self.Model);

                // TODO:  Show errors from the server's validation
            }

            error: ...
});
```

And in the ViewModel I do:

```
    var vm = new ViewModel();

    var d = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))); 
    self.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(d);

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And in my View.cshtml:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, "Description")
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { data_bind = "value: Model.Description" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
```

And the Model (in c#):

```
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

I hope this helps in your problem.

Comment: In fact my code if more complex, this is the simplified version.

Comment: thank you for answer but I am working with parial view. Is also ok? DO I need to enter data_bind for every model property?

Comment: All my views are partial.  And I use Ajax.  You could see the idea in my "solution", and adapt it to your problem.  :-)

Comment: Yes, data_bind for every model property.